# Is it feasible to measure voltage drop across 0-ohm jumper resistors to determine excessive current draw?

Tags: current-measurement, voltage-measurement, current-sensing

We design very low-power devices which in standby mode use about 8 µA of current. They are powered by 3 V lithium primary cells and are designed to last for many years.

Every now and then we see a failed component (usually a cracked ceramic capacitor) which can cause tens or hundreds of microamperes of leakage, and lead to an early dead battery.

There are several 0-ohm jumpers in various places which allow us to isolate or measure different sections of the circuit. In order to locate the failed component, we currently remove the jumper and insert an ammeter to narrow the search. Once the section is identified, we remove and replace decoupling capacitors until the cause is found.

I am thinking about the possibility of carefully measuring the jumpers rather than removing them, to speed up the troubleshooting process.

In reality, one particular 0603 0R jumper we are using measures about 23 mΩ (using a Kelvin measurement method). The voltage drop on a properly functioning unit would then be \$ 8 µA  \times 23 mΩ = 184 nV\$.

I realize that such a measurement requires an instrument such as a Keithley 2182A and special care to eliminate or reduce thermal EMF from temperature differences in dissimilar metals, oxide/contamination, etc.

Is pursing this line of thinking a worthwhile goal, or would it still be more efficient use of time to remove components and measure them using our current method?

I'll add that I believe the investment ($5k USD) will pay for itself in time savings if the measurements can be done reliably and are more expedient than removing and replacing components. Reliable measurements appear to involve more steps such as waiting for temperature stabilization, cleaning or removal of oxidation, and so forth; having not made measurements at this low level, I am uncertain of the actual process and whether it will be a net benefit.

Comment: Extending the concept further- measure the voltage drop across the pcb tracks to locate where excessive current is being drawn. I’ve used this technique a few times, but not for uA level measurements. You might be able to refine the process to the level where you probe specific points and compare the reading with a known good board. Get the data into Excel and write a script to identify the faulty component. I’d suggest using a current limited power source rather than the battery in order to raise the fault current levels if that works

Comment: IMO it will be always more reliable to remove the 0 Ohm jumpers. Measuring nanovolts may result in unclear diagnostics. Now, it also depends on how many devices you have to check per day/week/year and if it's worth the investment, knowing that it may not be the panacea and that an even more expensive bench multi meter may be necessary.

Comment: I would also explore ways to accelerate the process of unsoldering the jumpers.

Comment: @Fredled I agree that removing components is far more reliable. It just takes a fair amount of time, so I was thinking of ways to speed the process along. Also I'm not as concerned about exact measurements as I am in finding currents that are an order of magnitude larger than expected. e.g. Measuring for example 1µV instead of ~200nV would be indicative of ~40µA and represent a very common excess current draw. On the topic of removing components, we've gotten pretty fast with hot tweezers and air, but building some sort of automated jig would be more expensive than the 2182A.

Comment: How many PCB do you have to check? What's the volume? Is it temporary or you expect to do that for several months?

Comment: @Fredled This is in service of both manufactured units (failed some QC check) as well as RMA units from customers (early dead battery). Volumes vary but typically fewer than a few per week. The issue is that when a batch of defective units occurs, a number of employees spend a lot of time getting to the bottom of the cause(s). The ultimate goal is of course to have zero units, but with 500k+ products in the field, we inevitably will see a few here and there. The short-term objective is to ensure we have already made any necessary corrections in manufacturing/design.

Comment: Have you noticed any change with acoustics (cracks causing intermittent leakage) or temperature? Could a(n) (ultra)sonic probe excite the board and help identify failures, could heating components (say with a hot insulated probe, a ceramic hot-end -- oh, like in some soldering irons actually) help?

Comment: Are you using ceramic caps with flexible terminations?

Comment: Is always the same capacitors? Or maybe capacitors in one area of the board that gets flexed due to, say, a connector? Can the capacitors be tested before adding them to the board, just in case they are faulty at that stage?

Comment: Instead of 0-ohm jumpers, which rarely have specified resistances, I would suggest using accurate resistors in the range of 10 to 100 mΩ. You also need to take care with thermocouple effects; you're well down in the range where a small thermal potential can interfere with measurements.

Comment: @TimWilliams We can sometimes use hot air to identify cracked capacitors, but it changes the power consumption of the board by such a large amount that it drowns out the small effect we're looking for. I don't know about an ultrasonic probe, but this sounds like a potentially very helpful idea.

Comment: @bobflux No, unfortunately these are standard 0402 and 0603 MLCCs. (Inexpensive and present in a cost-sensitive mass-manufactured product.)

Comment: @AndrewMorton We have a database where we keep track of which components have failed. We have definitely found that the same location and nearby capacitors tend to be more frequent. We identified that flexing of the PCB when it was being snapped into an enclosure was responsible for a lot of problems. We altered that process and saw immediate improvements. We see far fewer problems after those changes. We have worked with manufacturers (Samsung, Murata, etc.) and effectively ruled out cap failures prior to PCB assembly. Device assembly and shipping/handling are candidates now.

Comment: @Hearth Wholeheartedly agree. These 0-ohm jumpers are definitely variable to a degree. But replacing them with higher-value resistors (while far better) takes the time we are seeking to reduce. The idea was to perform a Kelvin measurement on them in-circuit, and then attempt to identify branches with abnormally high current.

Comment: @JYelton I mean replace them in the BOM when the boards are first made.

Comment: @Hearth Oh I see. It's a possibility, depending on added cost. For now, the bulk of the devices were manufactured in the last few years and we're just ensuring that changes in manufacturing have already addressed failures.

Comment: I can't imagine the added cost will be much--resistors are very cheap. Honestly, at these currents, unless you're doing sensitive analog stuff you can probably use 1 or 10 Ω resistors, maybe even 100 Ω, and then have much more reasonable voltage drops that can be measured with ordinary multimeters.

Comment: Zero Ohm jumpers cost the same as normal resistors. With over half a million units, your management should be able to afford high precision measurement tools. Not only for that specific work but as an investment. Just my 2ct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answers provided are all very good and provided excellent insight. I am posting this answer because it outlines the equipment and methodology that we found acceptable.

The devices being diagnosed are generally customer returns because they had an earlier-than-expected failure (higher current consumption). They represent less than a tenth of a percent of purchased products, so the failure rate is very low. We generally perform the diagnostic as a means of determining the failure mode, which can alert us to a manufacturing or supplier problem (e.g. mishandling, process problem, faulty component lot, etc.). If a component failure is found on a product that was manufactured before that issue was addressed, we can disregard it. If the failure was not addressed or the manufacture date is after a remedy, then it is valuable data and is immediately utilized for quality assurance.

These are products manufactured in the last few years, so we aren't able to modify them as some answers suggest (certainly going forward, new revisions could incorporate some changes).

We were able to test with a Keithley 2182A nanovoltmeter as well as a DMM7510 7½-digit multimeter. Noise was not as big a factor as we had anticipated, but thermal offset and drift needed to be dealt with.

For example, a device that was pulling 300 µA (~40 times normal) was in for diagnosis. Normally we would remove jumpers and measure with an ammeter to determine which portion(s) of the board are pulling excess current. Here, the process was as follows:

1. Connect device to power (3 volts on a bench PSU limited to 500 mA).
2. Device is connected to an ammeter in series to monitor total current.
3. Connect DMM7510 in voltmeter mode to probes that can be left in contact with 0R resistor of interest. (We used shielded twisted pair wire connected to PCBite probes from [Sensepeek](https://sensepeek.com/); no affiliation. Shielded wire helped reduce noise and offset, keep the unshielded portion as short as possible.)

   [image: Probes]
4. Allow to thermally stabilize. Monitor the measured voltage until it exhibits less drift. (The remaining offset will be removed using relative mode.)
5. Disconnect power and short the power input to the device. We found this worked best using a source measure unit that can have its output terminals set to short instead of open when DUT power is switched off.

   The purpose of this step is to avoid having current flowing while removing the relative offset. There are two ways to do this: either have the power supply disconnected (high Z) or shorted. In high Z, the charge stored by on-board capacitors takes a very long time to dissipate. Shorted, bypass and bulk capacitance is drained in about 3 seconds (depending on test lead resistance, etc.). In the interest of speed and not having to touch the test setup and disturb it, we found shorting to be expedient and cause fewer issues.
6. Remove the relative offset on the DMM and reconnect power. Note the voltage measurement before it begins to drift. For example, a measurement across a 0R resistor that is at the device power input measured 7.2 µV. While this is not a good way to measure the actual resistance, it gave us a good-enough inference. Doing the math (\$7.2 µV / 300 µA = 23.3 mΩ\$) verifies that the 0R is in the order of magnitude expected.
7. Move the probes to a different 0R jumper on the board that provides power to a different domain. For example, we moved it to a jumper that is responsible for the microcontroller's digital domain. (Note that this also requires careful usage of microcontroller pins; we have taken great care to ensure that no GPIO pins are sinking or sourcing current elsewhere.)
8. Repeat the necessary above steps to allow stabilization and remove offset. We know that a "good" device only draws 5 µA in the microcontroller's digital domain, which means it would only have a voltage drop of 117 nV. This is a difficult value to measure, but remember we are looking for something orders-of-magnitude higher. Measuring this new 0R resistor, we measured ~6.8 µV, which represents ~291 µA if we assume the resistor is of the same resistance (23.3 mΩ). (This is not a valid assumption, because these resistors can vary, but it should be within the same power of ten, so for this investigation it's good enough.)

   [image: DMM] 
   *(Note, image is not representative of this specific case.)*
9. There are eight or so decoupling capacitors in this domain, which is far fewer than the rest of the board. We now remove them one at a time and monitor overall current draw. After removing only a few, current draw dropped from 300 to 8 µA indicating not only that the faulty component was found but that no other components were contributing factors.

While these steps may sound time-consuming, it is much quicker than removing components and measuring. Applying hot air and soldering tools to the board means we also have to wait for things to cool down to some extent before proceeding with diagnosis. Doing a few measurements, removing offsets, and being careful to control temperatures is about three to four times faster that we've experienced so far.

We also tested the Keithley 2182A nanovoltmeter, and achieved even better results (less noise, less offset). Ultimately, when trying to troubleshoot a device that's pulling 10% too much current (e.g. 8.8 µA instead of 8 µA), the nanovoltmeter is necessary and even then can be difficult. However, most faulty devices seem to have at least 4 times the current draw (32 µA) and often much higher (40x+).

Because the DMM7510 has current, voltage, resistance, digitizing, logging, etc. we felt it was the better fit. (This is not an endorsement of that particular product; any 7½-digit multimeter should do.) The savings in engineering and troubleshooting time will quickly justify the cost, and we have other uses for it, such as measuring strain gauges and other sensors/transducers.

**Summary:** Measuring hundreds of nanovolts accurately requires a few more steps and considerations than what one might be used to with more "conventional" voltage measurements that a lower-cost DMM performs. Small voltages from dissimilar metals, oxidation, thermal differences, and noise all become factors to mitigate. Using relative offset removal and being careful to achieve thermal equilibrium takes care of most of the uncertainty. If you're primarily looking for differences between, for example, 100 nV and 1 µV, the proposed method will work well. If you need precise measurements below 1 µV, you may need more environmental control and possibly more/different test gear.

Comment: A idea completly off-track from my side. If your common failure mode is cracked caps: You could try and inject some high frequency AC into your sub-domains one at a time and measure the resulting waveform or current draw or impedance or phase shift or what-ever. With a little bit of luck, you can determine if a domain is fault even if all domains are still interconnected via the 0R jumpers. IMHO worth a try. I got good results hunting down broken caps this way by injecting 100kHz sine into different test points on big boards with routed power.

Answer (score 9):

I am not sure this is going to be reliable- unless you have more than a few uV to work with it could be problematic. 100uV would be better. Also it will depend on the particular construction of that 0Ω resistor, and the manufacturer could change it at any time so long as it meets the maximum spec in the datasheet. And your PCBA house would have to get instructions not to substitute, since 0Ω is a pretty generic part.

Of course you could put a resistor like maybe 1Ω-20Ω in there rather than the 0Ω resistor, depending on the maximum current draw of your circuit it might not drop significant maximum voltage.

Perhaps you can test the PCB with pogo pins or a connector before the battery is installed. That would free up the expensive and hard to justify multimeter for more useful purposes.

Comment: At the current levels cited, 100 ohm or even 1000 ohm resistors instead of 0 ohm would do. Debugging the leaks will be possible with 20€ multimeter.

Comment: @fraxinus We know the standby level and approximate fault standby level but I don't see a number for the maximum current draw during normal operation as of now. In some products that's hundreds of mA or more so a large value resistor would be problematic.

Comment: Yes, we don'd. But the OP tells a story about multiple branches of the power bus that are dealt separately. Probably only one of them is high-power and for the rest, the idea is valid.

Comment: To help clear things up: The devices do indeed have a higher power section (an RF transmitter) that pulls 200 mA at most at sparse intervals. We generally don't care about this when trying to troubleshoot. For example, there are three or four sections of the circuit which are supplied power via a 0R jumper. In device sleep, the MCU section is about 75% of current consumption (5 µA) while other sections are ~1 µA. (Total of 8 µA.) The goal would be to identify branches that are drawing >50 or >100 µA. In a failed device, this seems to be our most common fault condition.

Comment: What's the current draw of the other sections when not sleeping?

Comment: Ruling in/out these sections with a quick but careful measurement (versus removing components) is the ultimate goal of this endeavor. Once we know, for example, that the section with a magnetic sensor and a small handful of decoupling caps is at fault, we can much more quickly identify which component(s) are leaking. In the past we discovered that physical stresses to the PCB were resulting in caps that were not shorted, but drawing >100 µA, and causing a failure that's difficult to detect before it goes out to the field.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Current draw of the various sections when not sleeping is still quite low, other than the RF section. There's a voltage booster section that can pull up to 60 mA. The other sections are less than 1 mA.

Answer (score 5):

I haven't done exactly what you're considering, but have made similar fault localization test jigs in the past.

I'd start with gold plated test points for each side of the 0R links as opposed to measuring directly on the resistors (or alternatively include discrete [pogo targets](https://www.digikey.com/short/j55dt343) to avoid the need for gold plating over whole board).  This will remove many of the contact problems, and open up the potential for a bed of nails / pogo test jig.

As you are looking for indicative readings at DC, I'd then explore the option of using a jig with low noise/offset opamps for each pair of pins to give enough amplification to feed a high resolution ADC allowing oversampling, averaging and offset adjustment, to give a simple go/no go indication.

I've found [this](https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/low-noise-inamp-nanovolt-sensitivity.html) app note provides some good advice on how to get very low noise, x2000 gain, which gets you into roughly the right region.

Combined with a microcontroller to do the averaging and offset calibration this potentially gives you a very quick localisation.

Alternatively, you could look at a high resolution differential ADC with built in chopper stabilized PGIA.  I've used the [Cirrus CS5534](https://statics.cirrus.com/pubs/proDatasheet/CS5531-32-33-34-AS_F7.pdf) 24-bit DAC before with great effect.  You can set the range down to +/-5mV (with the PGIA set to x64) and there is support for a guard signal to shield connections to the pins.  I've never used it down to the nV range, but with the built in oversampling support, suspect you might well be able to do well enough to spot the leakage signal.

Comment: We have considered making some DIY test equipment using opamps in parallel, but with design and build time costs, the idea of an "off the shelf" nanovoltmeter was looking appealing. Going forward I think it prudent to take advantage of our PCB ENIG finish and test points to facilitate measurements. For now we are tackling the existing products coming in for troubleshooting and unfortunately don't have many options.

Comment: If you are looking for an off-the-shelf option, perhaps worth looking at the CS5534 eval board https://statics.cirrus.com/pubs/rdDatasheet/CDB5534U-Z.pdf .  Much cheaper that the nV meter, and if it works for you could be the basis for a future full test jig.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it feasible to measure voltage drop across 0-ohm jumper resistors to determine excessive current draw?

I'd look from a non-technical perspective.

- The nanovoltmeter costs more than [5 grand](https://uk.farnell.com/keithley/2182a-e/nano-voltmeter-bench-100v-7-5digit/dp/2772524) to me.
- How much time would I save with this equipment?
- After how many days/weeks/months/years this equipment will pay for itself?

These questions would answer the biggest question: "Is it worth it?".

> *This equipment requires ... special care to eliminate or reduce thermal EMF from temperature differences in dissimilar metals, oxide/contamination, etc.*

I'd ignore these initially, but add them into the equation afterwards if the answer to the question above is "Yes".

Comment: I probably should have added that we've already determined that the investment would pay for itself in time savings, but only if the measurements can be conducted more quickly than removing and replacing components. It seems that because measurement could be more involved (waiting for temperatures to stabilize, thoroughly cleaning contact points, and so on) that it is difficult to really say yet. Hence my question. :)

Answer (score 3):

Detecting those low voltages without any further precautions will be very difficult, so this answer brings together some of the points of other answers, as you may need all of them

As Spehro suggests, use a finite value resistor. The actual value of a '0 ohm' resistor is not well defined, a real 1 or 10 ohm resistor will be.

As colintd suggests, use gold-plated test points on either side of the resistor. Together with gold plated probes, this will help eliminate much of the thermal / multi-metal / contamination potentials you will get at the contacts, that will confound your reading of tiny DC voltages.

Finally, my contribution - are you able to turn the board on and off relatively quickly? Looking for a change in DC potential at the test resistor will be far easier than interpretting a single reading that's very close to zero.

Comment: The board can be powered on and off quickly and repeatedly, however there is sufficient capacitance on the board such that the MCU stays on (no BOD) for several seconds in some cases. Are you suggesting measuring the resistor with the board completely unpowered (caps drained) and then compare that reading to its powered state?

Comment: With VDD/VBAT controlled by the tester, capacitance can be discharged by force, and evidently the PDN resistance is quite low, so the whole board can be discharged quickly (~ms) before taking additional measurements. Thus the measurement can be auto-zeroed (eliminates, at least in part, thermal EMF, if that should be a useful optimization -- too tight on space to add TPs for example), and basically you turn the problem from a DC nV problem (hard) to a nV AC problem (less hard); with a lock-in amplifier, your margin is simply however long you can afford to wait (~mHz BW --> sub-nV noise floor).

Answer (score 2):

I have done a lot of lab testing for my switching regulators (IQ in the 100s of nA).  If there is typically 8uA going through one of these resistors, you could use 10 Ohm resistors instead.  It would raise you off the noise floor a bit (on the order of 100uV vs 10nV) and give you a chance of actually detecting a signal that's bigger than expected (100uA=1mV). You could extend this to 100 or 1k Ohms if you were willing to live with a millivolt drop typically.  You're using resistors already; it would just be a slight BOM change.

Comment: This would work of course. But if we're going to remove 0R jumpers we just insert our ammeter and proceed with the troubleshooting that way. It wasn't clearly explained in my question, but this is in the context of troubleshooting existing products that come in for replacement. (Going forward, we could tweak the product design to make troubleshooting easier.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative idea:  gradually increase the voltage while recording with an infrared camera.

A leaky component will warm up more quickly than the normal version of that part.

Be careful not to release the magic smoke ;)

Comment: This would work for situations where there's a dead short, perhaps, but the very small leakage current I'm looking at (500µA and often much less) doesn't allow for raising the voltage at all without harming semiconductor components such as the microcontroller. In order to see a failed component with our thermal camera, we need something (I'm guessing) in the order of ~200 mW. At these ultra-low currents, there's barely hundreds of µW being consumed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about your design - how sensitive it is to parasitics, how many of these resistors you're using, what envelope or environmental limitations you have, or if you can even spin new boards - but a potentially low cost solution would be to add a 1.27mm header in the place of your jumper resistor higher failure rate circuits. You can keep it shorted with a jumper, then remove the jumper to insert your current measurement tool.

This would add stray inductance and at higher frequencies these jumpers would act like small antennas, so if this design is low voltage or analog, or if you're EMI constrained, it would be a no-go. But I've always been a fan of the KISS model where it's appropriate.

Comment: It would be handy to have some little jumpers like you describe, but again these are existing products in the field that come in for replacement/diagnosis. They have radio transceivers on board so we wouldn't want to add header-style jumpers.

Answer (score 0):

I will propose a very simple but effective solution that does not require additional investments. It has only one drawback - that it is unlikely that it can be carried out... but it is still worth a try.

My idea is to use (if possible) the voltage drops across existing resistors in the circuit caused by the leakage currents flowing through them. Since they are certainly much larger than the drops across zero-resistance "resistors", you can use a simple voltmeter to measure them.